# How to exclude markers with zero coordinates from array while making auto-center

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

guys!
Please, help me to solve a strange problem.
Here we have a customized google map with a number of objects in an array. I've made auto-center using fitBounds. Unfortunately some objects has (0,0) coordinates. In my example you can see only one of them but in final version all data will be taken from a remote XML file and there are several such zero-coords objects there.

I'm a noob in JS so is there a simple way to filter objects with (0,0) coordinates and ignore them when making auto-center?

Here is my code:

```
var locations = [
    ['1573785', 37.92904993, -0.73309714, '180000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573785/1-1.jpg', '0', '82.00', '0', 'Orihuela Costa'],
  ['1573813', 0, 0, '14900000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573813/1-1.jpg', '0', '82.00', '0', 'La Manga del Mar Menor'],
  ['1573853', 37.9081557, -0.743851199999995, '595000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573853/3-1.jpg', '0', '82.00', '0', 'Orihuela Costa'],
['1573868', 38.3668300727851, -0.5013084776552583, '1750000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573868/1-1.jpg', '43', '2000', '43','Alicante'],
['1573874', 37.94373250149462, -0.7567906379699707, '1200000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573874/1-1.jpg', '0', '600', '2', 'Orihuela Costa'],
['1573909', 37.8970045617763, -0.754108428955078, '210000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573909/4-1.jpg', '4', '90', '2', 'Orihuela Costa'],
['1573877', 37.922449854629846, -0.7286167144775391, '12000000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573877/2-1.jpg', '1', '110', '1', 'Orihuela Costa'],
['1573879', 37.9095917, -0.74301330000003, '260000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573879/4-1.jpg', '2', '78', '1', 'Orihuela Costa'],
['1573896', 37.9144430700431, -0.725269317626953, '1995000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573896/5-1.jpg', '5', '477', '5', 'Orihuela Costa'],
['Дом в Кабо Роиг', 37.916156, -0.724545199999966, '615000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573921/4-1.jpg', '1', '195', '2', 'Orihuela Costa'],
['Вилла в Кампоамор', 37.9066009, -0.745517599999971, '1400000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573967/4-1.jpg', '5', '550', '4', 'Orihuela Costa'],
['1573968', 37.94675263827021, -0.7060861587524414, '140000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573968/4-1.jpg', '2', '67', '1', 'Torrevieja'],
['1573969', 37.942556074154616, -0.7123517990112305, '135000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573969/4-1.jpg', '3', '103', '1', 'Torrevieja'],
['1573982', 37.909499757334224, -0.7429933547973633, '140000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573982/8-1.jpg', '3', '83', '2', 'Orihuela Costa'],
['1573983', 37.9391007, -0.7477284000000282, '130000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573983/3-1.jpg', '2', '98', '1', 'Orihuela Costa']
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.922, -0.728),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
});

var limits = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;
var gmarkers = [];
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: {
    url: 'https://i.postimg.cc/CxLgfgXj/map-price-marker-1.png',
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(60, 20)
      },
      label: {
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Marker(9, 8),
    text: locations[i][3],
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    fontSize: "13px",
    fontWeight: "standard",
    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
  },  
  
    });
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent('<div id="iw-container">' +
    '<div>' +'<div class="house_card__label new_object">' +'<span>новинка</span>' + '</div>' +'</div>' +
    '<div class="image">' + '<a href="realty/villas/'+ locations[i][0] +'">' +'<img src="'+ locations[i][4] +'">' +'</a>' +'</div>' +
    '<div class="house_card__info">' +
        '<a href="realty/villas/'+ locations[i][0] +'">' +'<h4>' + locations[i][0] +'</h4></a>' +
        '<p class="house_price">'+ locations[i][3] +'</p>' +
        '<div class="house_features">' +
        '<span>Количество спален:</span>' +
        '<span>'+ locations[i][5] +'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="house_features">' +
        '<span>Жилая площадь (м²):</span>' +
        '<span>'+ locations[i][6] +'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="house_features">' +
        '<span>Количество ванных:</span>' +
        '<span>'+ locations[i][7] +'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="house_location">' +
        '<div class="house_location__text">'+ locations[i][8] +'</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>');
            infowindow.open(map, marker);     
        }
    })(marker, i));
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    
    limits.extend(marker.position);
    map.fitBounds(limits);
    
   }
 var styles = [{
    fontFamily:'Montserrat',
    fontWeight:'400',
    textColor:'#FFFFFF',
    textSize:'13',
    url: 'https://i.postimg.cc/6pjNrPxF/map-cluster-1.png',
    height: 63,
    width: 65,
}]
  var clusterOptions = {gridSize: 30, maxZoom: 16, "styles":styles};
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers, clusterOptions);
```

And the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snoflak/yf13zgqb/277/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `filter` method to filter out the elements with the `0` cords as follow:

```
locations.filter((index) => index[1] != 0 && index[2] != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to skip the marker creation if both coordinates are 0:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  if (locations[i][1] == 0 && locations[i][2] == 0)
    continue;
  // existing marker creation code ...
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/k6btuLjv/)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
var locations = [
  ['1573785', 37.92904993, -0.73309714, '180000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573785/1-1.jpg', '0', '82.00', '0', 'Orihuela Costa'],
  ['1573813', 0, 0, '14900000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573813/1-1.jpg', '0', '82.00', '0', 'La Manga del Mar Menor'],
  ['1573853', 37.9081557, -0.743851199999995, '595000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573853/3-1.jpg', '0', '82.00', '0', 'Orihuela Costa'],
  ['1573868', 38.3668300727851, -0.5013084776552583, '1750000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573868/1-1.jpg', '43', '2000', '43', 'Alicante'],
  ['1573874', 37.94373250149462, -0.7567906379699707, '1200000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573874/1-1.jpg', '0', '600', '2', 'Orihuela Costa'],
  ['1573909', 37.8970045617763, -0.754108428955078, '210000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573909/4-1.jpg', '4', '90', '2', 'Orihuela Costa'],
  ['1573877', 37.922449854629846, -0.7286167144775391, '12000000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573877/2-1.jpg', '1', '110', '1', 'Orihuela Costa'],
  ['1573879', 37.9095917, -0.74301330000003, '260000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573879/4-1.jpg', '2', '78', '1', 'Orihuela Costa'],
  ['1573896', 37.9144430700431, -0.725269317626953, '1995000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573896/5-1.jpg', '5', '477', '5', 'Orihuela Costa'],
  ['Дом в Кабо Роиг', 37.916156, -0.724545199999966, '615000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573921/4-1.jpg', '1', '195', '2', 'Orihuela Costa'],
  ['Вилла в Кампоамор', 37.9066009, -0.745517599999971, '1400000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573967/4-1.jpg', '5', '550', '4', 'Orihuela Costa'],
  ['1573968', 37.94675263827021, -0.7060861587524414, '140000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573968/4-1.jpg', '2', '67', '1', 'Torrevieja'],
  ['1573969', 37.942556074154616, -0.7123517990112305, '135000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573969/4-1.jpg', '3', '103', '1', 'Torrevieja'],
  ['1573982', 37.909499757334224, -0.7429933547973633, '140000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573982/8-1.jpg', '3', '83', '2', 'Orihuela Costa'],
  ['1573983', 37.9391007, -0.7477284000000282, '130000 €', 'https://fotos15.apinmo.com/2344/1573983/3-1.jpg', '2', '98', '1', 'Orihuela Costa']
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 12,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.922, -0.728),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var limits = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;
var gmarkers = [];
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  //var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
  console.log("lat=" + locations[i][1] + ", lng=" + locations[i][2]);
  if (locations[i][1] == 0 && locations[i][2] == 0)
    continue;

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: {
      url: 'https://i.postimg.cc/CxLgfgXj/map-price-marker-1.png',
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(60, 20)
    },
    label: {
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Marker(9, 8),
      text: locations[i][3],
      color: "#FFFFFF",
      fontSize: "13px",
      fontWeight: "standard",
      fontFamily: "Montserrat",
    },

  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent('<div id="iw-container">' +
        '<div>' + '<div class="house_card__label new_object">' + '<span>новинка</span>' + '</div>' + '</div>' +
        '<div class="image">' + '<a href="realty/villas/' + locations[i][0] + '">' + '<img src="' + locations[i][4] + '">' + '</a>' + '</div>' +
        '<div class="house_card__info">' +
        '<a href="realty/villas/' + locations[i][0] + '">' + '<h4>' + locations[i][0] + '</h4></a>' +
        '<p class="house_price">' + locations[i][3] + '</p>' +
        '<div class="house_features">' +
        '<span>Количество спален:</span>' +
        '<span>' + locations[i][5] + '</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="house_features">' +
        '<span>Жилая площадь (м²):</span>' +
        '<span>' + locations[i][6] + '</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="house_features">' +
        '<span>Количество ванных:</span>' +
        '<span>' + locations[i][7] + '</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="house_location">' +
        '<div class="house_location__text">' + locations[i][8] + '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>');
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
  gmarkers.push(marker);

  limits.extend(marker.position);
  map.fitBounds(limits);

}
var styles = [{
  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
  fontWeight: '400',
  textColor: '#FFFFFF',
  textSize: '13',
  url: 'https://i.postimg.cc/6pjNrPxF/map-cluster-1.png',
  height: 63,
  width: 65,
}]
var clusterOptions = {
  gridSize: 30,
  maxZoom: 16,
  /* "styles":styles, */
  imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
};
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers, clusterOptions);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500;600&display=swap');
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>
<style>
  #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #CCC;
  }
  
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .gm-style .gm-style-iw-t::after {
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  
  .gm-style .gm-style-iw-c {
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  
  .gm-style .gm-style-iw-d {
    overflow: hidden !important;
  }
  
  button.gm-ui-hover-effect {
    background: url(https://i.postimg.cc/8PGDNWbX/xs.png) !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    right: -9px !important;
  }
  
  button.gm-ui-hover-effect img {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  .gm-style-iw {
    width: 250px !important;
    height: 370px !important;
    top: 5px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 #979ca54c !important;
    border-radius: 20px !important;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', monospace !important;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
  }
  
  .gm-style-iw img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 187px;
  }
  
  .gm-style-iw a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #000 !important;
  }
  
  .gm-style-iw h4 {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    margin: 12px 0 10px 0 !important;
  }
  
  .gm-style-iw .house_price {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    line-height: 24px !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    color: #5dbfc5 !important;
    margin: 0 0 9px 0 !important;
  }
  
  .gm-style-iw .house_features {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.42;
    color: #a1a1a1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .gm-style-iw .house_features span:last-child {
    text-align: right;
    color: #5dbfc5;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  }
  
  .gm-style-iw .house_location {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
  }
  
  .gm-style-iw .house_location__text {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #5dbfc5;
    padding: 0 0 0 26px;
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/GhjR227L/pin-1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    background-size: 21px 26px;
    ;
  }
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
```